# Conditional Formatting in Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formatting, prawn

Is it possible to utilize conditional formatting in Prawn? For example, would I be able to check the return value from a form and either output a "Yes" or "No" based on its result? Say it looked like the following in my pdf class.

```
def method
   text "Approved?" + #resultHere
end
```

Is something like this achievable?

Comment: Can you clarify the use of the form a bit more?  Is this a Rails form that is used to capture data and then you generate a pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Something like the following should work. I guess I just hit a wall and didn't notice the obvious.

```
def method
   if @form.attribute
     text "You answered: Yes"
   else
     text "You answered: No"
   end
 end
```